# How to run multiple scenarios with different protocols sequentially?

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I have 2 scenarios

```
val scn = scenario("getJson").exec(getJson).inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpProtocol)
val scn1 = scenario("sendJson").exec(processJsons).inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(amqpConf)
```

I want to run them sequentially in Gatling 3.5.1
I tried these ways

```
1. setup(scn,scn1)
2. scn.andThen(scn1)
   setup(scn)
```

but both ways it is not working, everytime scn1 is executed first.
Someone please help me. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gatling DSL components are immutable, so 2 is broken, you're passing the unchained scn.

```scala
setUp(
 scn.andThen(scn1)
)
```

or

```scala
val chained = scn.andThen(scn1)
setUp(chained)
```

Comment: I tried both ways, still, it is taking scn1 first

Comment: I have to insist. Please check your code.

Comment: You are correct, the issue was in my code, I resolved it and this solution is working, thanks